# In Delphi 2010, the Click event processed despite the corresponding button being disabled

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-2010

Consider the following piece of code executed within the OnClick event of a given button:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  button1.enabled := false;    //Line 1  
  application.processmessages; //Line 2  
  Sleep(3000);                 //Line 3
  button1.enabled := True;     //Line 4
  Release;                     //Line 5
end;
```

In Delphi 2010, if after clicking this button you manage to perform yet another 
click on it while the execution is busy in Line 3, the subsequent click 
event will apparently get stored in the queue of commands, thus when 
Release(Line 5) procedure is called, the application will attempt to process 
it. Consequently the click event will be triggered once again. The second time
around, the button component has already been destroyed, hence "access violation" error get's raised.

The whole concept of acknowledging the second click by the system when the respective 
button is disabled does not seem to be sound. Any explanations to this shady behavior?

Comment: That's what you get when you use the evil Application.Processmessages. A sound hint, if you have some long processing to do, move it to another thread...

Comment: `Release()` is also a queued command, so any clicks already in the message queue before `Release()` is called will be processed before the Form gets freed.

Comment: In Delphi 10.3, the issue depicted above is not replicable anymore. Apparently they have introduced some adjustments to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system is behaving exactly as designed, but be aware that your code is going against all sound design principles. Specifically the use of `Sleep` and `ProcessMessages` in an input event handler are both to be frowned upon.

The reason that the program behaves this way is as follows:

1. The user generates an input message by clicking the mouse.
2. This input event is placed in the input queue for the appropriate thread.
3. That thread is not servicing its input queue (it is sleeping) and so the input message, which is a mouse down, mouse up combo, sits there.
4. The thread wakes up and enables the button.
5. The button `OnClick` handler returns and the application's message loop continues.
6. In due course the mouse down and mouse up messages are processed (before the `CM_RELEASE` message) and so the button `OnClick` handler runs again.
7. The button `OnClick` handler calls `ProcessMessages` which then handles the `CM_RELEASE` and kills the form.
8. BOOM!

> The whole concept of acknowledging the second click by the system when the respective button is disabled does not seem to be sound.

The key point is that the enabled state of the button is checked when the input message is *processed* and not when the input message is *generated*. It has to be this way because input messages are extremely low level things, and it's only the application that can interpret them as things like button clicks.

There are plenty of ways to fix your code, but I'm loathe to suggest any because this is clearly code for illustration. But I will say that all sound solutions will involve the removal of the calls to `Sleep` and `ProcessMessages.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation David. It's just that i would've expected the system to refrain from accepting a button click message in the queue, when the button itself is disabled AT THE TIME OF THE CLICK.
As you've pointed out, this is just a sample code for illustration. The real instance i've encountered is a case where some lengthy procedures are executed at the location where i've introduced the SLEEP function above.

Comment: @Khatchig The point is that the system does not put a button click message in the queue. It puts a mouse down/up pair of events in the queue. Only the application itself can determined what to do with that pair of events. In your case its a standard windows BUTTON control. But what about a custom control that implements `Enabled` in its own way? How can the input event generator know about that.

Answer (score 0):

During the Sleep your application is non responsive. The click message is queued and is only processed after you re-enabled the button (actually after the event handler method is fully executed and the application has gone idle again).

To solve it, also execute Application.ProcessMessages after sleep, before enabling the button. That will empty your message queue first and will discard the click message.

Or just don't enable the button at all. Why would you, if you're going to release the form anyway?

A (probably) better solution would be to execute the Sleep in a separate thread, but since Sleep here is probably just a stub for some real code, it's hard to say how much effort it will take to do that.

Anyway, your current application isn't good, and calling Application.ProcessMessages in situations like this is likely to generate 'random' bugs once in a while. The best you can do is limit the risk, but there is no good way to solve it, other than radically change this implementation.

Comment: *To solve it, also execute Application.ProcessMessages after sleep, before enabling the button. That will empty your message queue first and will discard the click message.* Even then there would be a hole. After the extra call to ProcessMessages returned, and before Release was called, any input messages would be added to the the queue ahead of `CM_RELEASE`. And then we'd be back to square one. The entire approach here is fundamentally broken.

Comment: Yes. Come to think of it, why would you even re-enable the button if you're going to release the form anyway...

Comment: @GolezTol, re-enabling the button is indeed meaningless in the sample code above as you pointed out. I was just curious about the behavior of Delphi in such a case.